# Entity without Primary Key ID

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Hi I want to create an Entity which doesn't have an ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROD_LIC_TYPE_ALL")
public class UserProdLicTypeAll {
   @EmbeddedId
   private UserProdLicTypeAllPK id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LICENSE_TYPE_ID") 
    private LicenseType licType;
    ....
  }
```

since it doesn't have primary key i created Embeddable class as below:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class UserProdLicTypeAllPK {

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="LICENSE_TYPE_ID")
  private LicenseType licType;
  ...
 }
```

The combination of these two fields returns a unique value. 
But it doesn't work.  I get

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  exception`.

Do i need to have references in User and LicenseType entities for both UserProdLicTypeAll and UserProdLicTypeAllPK? I have tried that also but still it doesn't work.

Comment: The exception you get doesn't seem to have any relationship with Hibernate. When asking about an exception, ALWAYS post the complete exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is my private hell. I'm not sure what the best way to solve it properly.

My best solution is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TableName.AREA_USER)
@IdClass(UserAreaPK.class)
public class UserArea implements Serializable {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = UserAreaPK.C_AREA_ID)
    private Long areaId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = UserAreaPK.C_USER_ID)
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = UserAreaPK.C_AREA_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Area area;
```

And

```
/**
 * Primary key for the relationship  User-Area
 */
public class UserAreaPK implements Serializable {

    protected static final String   C_AREA_ID           = "area_id";
    protected static final String   C_USER_ID           = "user_id";
    private static final long       serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = C_AREA_ID)
    private Long                    areaId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = C_USER_ID)
    private String                  userId;
```