# JPA Entity Without Keys in PosgtreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee

PROBLEM: I don't have keys in database table and changing schema is forbidden. Fields are `date` and `some_int`. If no field is annotated as key, then Intellij shows error "Persistent entity 'MyEntity' should have primary key".

RESEARCH: Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208566/entity-without-primary-key-id) suggest composite keys only. Choices of `@Id`, `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass` doesn't solve the problem.

QUESTION: How to build a JPA Entity?

```
create table my_table
(
 region_id integer,
  period    date,
  income    bigint
);
```

Comment: An entity must have an ID, which must be unique and immutable. There's no way around it. If you think one of your attempts does define a unique, immutable composite ID and should work, then post the code of your attempt, tell precisely what you did what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. We won't repeat the documentation and examples of these annotations here: they're already documented.

Comment: What DB? do you need insert,update or is it read only? You may find workaround using views and triggers, but it would be better to use natveSql queries and map them to Pojo. see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

Comment: Either you define how the "key" is possible, or you use a JPA provider that allows persistence of an entity without a `@Id` field (DataNucleus JPA allows "nondurable identity" for that case)